# OpenGL: Copy texture to main memory

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, unity-game-engine

For a project in Unity, I'm resorting to writing a native (C++) plugin where my goal is to get the texture data into main system memory. I'm aware that Unity provides a similar function to already achieve this (`Texture2D.GetRawTextureData()`). The unfortunate side-effect of calling this function is that it allocates a large chunk of memory every call, and I'm running this call every frame which triggers the garbage collection quite often (read: every frame)

So my attempt here is to write a similar function that uses a pre-allocated buffer, pass the address of the buffer to the C++ plugin and copy the texture data into this. However, the texture data returned is all black (so all values set to 0). What am I doing wrong, or what did I forget to take into account in retrieving this data?

The code in Unity (C#) calling the plugin is as follows:

```
private Texture2D tempTexture = null;
private byte[] textureBuffer = null;
private IntPtr textureHandle;

public void StartStream(StreamerOptions options)
{
    ...
    tempTexture = new Texture2D(options.width, options.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    textureBuffer = new byte[options.width * options.height * 4];
    textureHandle = tempTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr();
    ...
}

private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    if (IsStreaming)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(source, destination, material, 0);
        tempTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, attachedCamera.targetTexture.width, attachedCamera.targetTexture.height), 0, 0, false);
        tempTexture.Apply();
    }
}

private void OnPostRender()
{
    if (IsStreaming)
    {
        FetchTexture(textureHandle, textureBuffer);
        pipe.Write(textureBuffer);
        // pipe.Write(tempTexture.GetRawTextureData());
    }
}
```

In the function `OnPostRender` I call the plugin to fetch the texture data. The C++ code retrieving the OpenGL is as follows:

```
void RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES::FetchTextureData(void *textureHandle, uint8_t *textureData)
{
    GLuint glTextureName = static_cast<GLuint>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(textureHandle));
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureName);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, textureData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, by using the solution found on Unity Answers:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1305191/glreadpixels-from-a-rendertexture.html

I used the example unity native-plugin project as a base and started stripping away the functionality I didn't need.

The most important part of this was initializing the GLEW sub-system.

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();
glGetError(); // Clean up error generated by glewInit
```

After that, I could start reading in texture data using the code in the linked answer:

```
void RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES::ReadPixels(void *data, int textureWidth, int textureHeight)
{
   int currentFBORead;
   int currentFBOWrite;
   glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &currentFBORead);
   glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &currentFBOWrite);

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFBOWrite);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFBORead);
}
```